# Explanation of the proof of $\phi(n)\cdot \frac{n}{2}=\sum_{a\in R}a$

Tags: proof-explanation, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

In my number theory textbook, there is a theorem about *Euler's Phi Function* it says:

**A Theorem:**

If $R$ is a reduced residue system modulo $n$: $R=\{a\in C \mid \gcd(a,n)=1\}$ Where $C$ is a complete residue system modulo $n$, so:

$$\sum_{a\in R}a=\phi(n)\cdot \frac{n}{2}$$ Where $\sum_{a\in R}a$ is the sum of all elements in $R$.

**The Proof:**

since R is a reduced residue system mod $n$ so $\mid R\mid = \phi(n)$ Hence we can suppose that $R=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{\phi(n)}\}$ Thus:
$$S=\sum_{a\in R}a=\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}a_i$$ But since $\gcd(a_i,n)=1 \iff \gcd(n-a_i,n)=1$ so :$$\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}(n-a_i)$$
$$ \implies2S = \sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}(n-a_i)=\phi(n)\cdot n$$
$$\iff S= \phi(n)\cdot \frac{n}{2}$$

Ok Everything is clear but this transition: $$\gcd(a_i,n)=1 \iff \gcd(n-a_i,n)=1$$
is not clear for me, and even if it is how can this statement implies this ?$$\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\phi(n)}(n-a_i)$$

Comment: The statement as is cannot be true because we can have reduced residue systems modulo $n$ with arbitrarily large elements.

Comment: what's wrong with the statement?

Comment: $R=\{11\}$ is a reduced residue system modulo $2$, but the statement fails for this $R$.

Comment: The flaw in the proof is that $a \in R$ does not imply $n-a \in R$, for $R$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assume $\gcd(a_i,n)=1$. We want to show that $\gcd(n-a_i,n)=1$. $$\gcd(n-a_i,n)\mid -(n-a_i)+n=a_i$$ Now we see that $\gcd(n-a_i,n)$ divides all three $n-a_i,n,a_i$ therefore $\gcd(n-a_i,n)\mid \gcd(a_i,n)=1$. This is only possible if $\gcd(n-a_i,a_i)=1$.
- Assume that $\gcd(n-a_i,n)=1$. We now want to show that $\gcd(a_i, n)=1$. $$\gcd(a_i,n)\mid n-a_i$$ Again, we see that $\gcd(a_i,n)$ divides all three $n-a_i, a_i, n$, in particular $\gcd(a_i,n)\mid\gcd(n-a_i, n)=1$. This is only possible if $\gcd(a_i, n)=1$.